# Code coverage for people (manual) tests?

Tags: .net, testing, code-coverage

Are there any code coverage tools for manual testing?  For example, if I write 30 new lines of code, compile, then run, is there any way to quickly verify that all 30 lines were run?

Also, later, after I've checked the code into an official build, is there any way that I can verify that the test department hit on all 30 lines of code when they conducted their independent testing?

I know that there are a lot of tools for verifying that test departments test all requirements, but I haven't found a tool that verifies that testers test all lines of code.

I'm most interested in .NET / C# tools.

Comment: dotCover theoretically does this but in practice it has never worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Using Code Coverage with Manual Testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcalt/archive/2006/07/02/654157.aspx)

Comment: The link is dead, but I managed to find a copy in Web Archive - https://web.archive.org/web/20070313165122/http://blogs.msdn.com/marcalt/archive/2006/07/02/654157.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Getting 100% coverage is probably overkill -- and there are some cases where even when all lines are covered, the tool may not show it.  That being said, you should check out the code coverage tools in Visual Studio Team System or any of a number of external coverage tools, such as [nCover](http://www.ncover.com/).  Team System allows you to define testing-related checkin policies that may allow you to do what you want with regard to making sure that checked in code has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out [AutomatedQA](http://automatedqa.com)'s tools.  They can do code coverage with manual testing *and* they have tools for automating the manual tests which also can be coupled with code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more detailed answer rather than just a link:

To do this for an IIS Express application:

Instrument the dlls you want to see coverage for. So in your bin directory run this

```
vsintr /coverage yourapp.dll
```

I haven't figured out how to make it utilize wildcards unfortunately.

Launch the app

```
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:run.coverage
```

- launch your app
- If IIS Express app:

  - Get the name of the site from `C:\Users\<your user>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

run your manual tests,
then to finish

```
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

from related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791306/57883

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved using dotnet-coverage tool where am able to capture all coverage % during manual or automation tests

**Prerequisite**:  dotnet needs to be installed.
To install the latest release version of the dotnet-coverage NuGet package, use the dotnet tool install command:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage`

`dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool`

Navigate to “\ Execute below line from project location . this will collect data based on project and pdb function in .coverage file

`dotnet-coverage collect dotnet run`

Launches the application in localhost :5000

execute some scenarios After some actions or you can run any automation scripts then click ctrl+C to close the run – output.coverage will get created

```
After executing the scripts output.coverage is getting generated  so we need to merge this output.coverage to .xml with below function
```

`dotnet-coverage merge -o output.xml -f xml output.coverage`

From output.xml using report generator crate html report
ReportGenerator -reports:C:\Analytics_Application\analyticscoredev\Temenos.Insight\Temenos.InsightWeb\output.xml -targetdir:C:\SampleAppPlus\CoverageReports\html -sourcedirs:C:\SampleAppPlus

Answer (score 0):

**Accepted Answer Link - https://web.archive.org/web/20070313165122/http://blogs.msdn.com/marcalt/archive/2006/07/02/654157.aspx**

*Pasting it here, just in case if we loose it. I haven't tested the solution*

Because of the flexible Team System Testing Infrastructure design you set this up just the way you do it with other tests you want to instrument:
Open up the “test run Configuration” by double clicking the file “localtestrun.testrunconfig” under the solution items. There you just navigate to code coverage and add/mark the assemblies you want to instrument.

Afterwards start the test and then be sure to start the Application you are testing in the assembly path you defined during add/mark, normally <project>\bin\debug.

Now just start testing the application to satisfy the manual test. Before you Apply the manual test be sure to shut down the application, for code coverage results to save.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a console app you can use for manual code coverage, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-code-coverage-console-tool?view=vs-2022

To summarize, you can get manual coverage using four steps:

1. Instrument your binary: `Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console instrument --session-id 73c34ce5-501c-4369-a4cb-04d31427d1a4 MyApplication.exe`
2. Start the coverage tool in server mode, with an arbitrary session-id: `Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console collect --session-id 73c34ce5-501c-4369-a4cb-04d31427d1a4 --server-mode`
3. Run your application and exercise whatever scenarios you want
4. Shutdown the code coverage server `Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console shutdown 73c34ce5-501c-4369-a4cb-04d31427d1a4`

This will output a file, called `output.coverage` by default, which you can open in VS to view your coverage!