# Batch running of VS code coverage tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I came up a batch file to generate code coverage file as is written in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951089/how-to-use-ms-code-coverage-tool-in-command-line).

```
cl /Zi hello.cpp -link /Profile
vsinstr -coverage hello.exe
start vsperfmon /coverage /output:run.coverage
hello
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

However, I got this error message when I run the batch file.

[image]

I had to run `vsperfcmd /shutdown` manually to finish it. 
What might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a timing issue.

The `start vsperfmon /coverage /output:run.coverage` command starts up vsperfmon.exe in a separate process.

Concurrently, your script goes on to run `hello`.  If `hello` is a really simple program, it is possible that it executes and completes before vsperfmon.exe is running and fully initialized.  If your script hits `vsperfcmd /shutdown` before the monitor is up and running, you will get the error you're showing.

`vsperfcmd` is just a controller/launcher for `vsperfmon`, so you can use that exclusively in your batch file:

```
cl /Zi hello.cpp -link /Profile
vsinstr -coverage hello.exe
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:run.coverage
hello
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

In this case, the first call to `vsperfcmd` will block until the monitor is up and fully running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and it works like a charm. Could you help me out this question also? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965173/generating-coverage-file-programmatic-way-with-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Zam!!!!!!! "vsperfcmd is just a controller/launcher for vsperfmon" was the hint I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To do this for already instrumented files with an IIS Express application:
Get the name of the site from `C:\Users\<your user>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

```
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:run.coverage
"c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /site:"<that thing you got from applicationhost.config>"
```

a browser will likely auto launch. click around in your code, do your manual tests.

then to finish

```
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```