# Generating .coverage file programmatic way with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage, profiler

I need to generate .coverage file programmatic way. [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms_joc/archive/2005/04/08/406608.aspx) explains a C# code to do it as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis;

// You must add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll

namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio
{
       class DumpProgram
       {
              static void Main(string[] args)
              {
                    Process p = new Process();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/COVERAGE ");
                    sb.Append("hello.exe");
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = "vsinstr.exe";
                    p.StartInfo.Arguments = sb.ToString();
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                     // TODO: Look at return code – 0 for success
                     // A guid is used to keep track of the run
                    Guid myrunguid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    Monitor m = new Monitor();
                    m.StartRunCoverage(myrunguid, "hello.coverage");
                    // Complete the run
                    m.FinishRunCoverage(myrunguid);
```

Unfortunately, when I compile this code, I get the following error.

```
bin2xml.cs(26,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Monitor' could not be found (are you
        missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
bin2xml.cs(26,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Monitor' could not be found (are you
        missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

As [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) says, there are some changes between VS2008 and VS2010, I think the Monitor class is in some different namespace.

What might be wrong? How can I generate the .coverage file programmatically with Visual Studio 2010?

### SOLVED

1. Copy the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll from Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x86
2. Add `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeCoverage;` in the source code
3. Run `csc bin2xml.cs /r:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll /r:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll`.

Comment: did you add ref to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll

Comment: @K lvanov : I can't find the dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies directory (VS2010 Ultimate version).

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coverage monitor DLL (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll`) is really just a glorified wrapper around vsperfmon.exe.  Literally, the arguments you pass in just become command-line arguments to the process.

The easiest solution is to just use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to run vsperfmon.exe yourself (similar to what you're doing for vsinstr.exe).

If you want to use the coverage monitor DLL, you need to add a reference to it.  There is a 32- and 64-bit vsperfmon.exe (for collecting code coverage against 32- and 64-bit processes, respectively), so there is also a 32- and 64-bit version of the coverage monitor DLL.

For VS2010, the 32-bit coverage monitor DLL lives in `Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x86`.  The 64-bit coverage monitor DLL lives in `Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x64`.

If you want to support collection on both 32- and 64-bit processes, you'll need to have a 32- and 64-bit version of your collection program if you also want to use the coverage monitor DLL (since the coverage monitor DLL is *not* system-agnostic MSIL).  If you just create the vsperfmon.exe process yourself, you'd only need to have one version of your collection program to support both 32- and 64-bit processes.

Comment: @Chris : It sounds like that for getting the .coverage file, programmatic approach isn't so attractive, as one can use the batch method easily. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958776/batch-running-of-vs-code-coverage-tools

Comment: @Chris: adding `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor;` gives me "bin2xml.cs(7,39): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Monitor' does not exist in the namespace
        'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" error. What might be wrong?

Comment: @prosseek: you can't do `using` on a type, you just need to use the namespace: `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage;`  Then, the `Monitor` type should be available.  You'll want to avoid `using System.Threading;` since that namespace also contains a `Monitor` type.

Comment: @Chris : I tried without the `using ..Coverage`, but I got the errors. I updated the original post. Could you check that?

Comment: @prosseek: sorry, I was mistaken in my comments here, the correct namespace usage is `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeCoverage;`.  If you right-click on the assembly reference in Solution Explorer, you can select "View in Object Browser" to see the namespaces and types defined in the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

it should be part of `System.Threading` namespace, but not in your case

Update: this explains it all http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: see if that info will help http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/06/14/running-code-coverage-in-tfs2010-builds/

Comment: @K Ivanov: He's referring to the code coverage monitor, not the `lock` monitor.