# Code Coverage for a dotnet core application through manual testing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, code-coverage

I'm trying to get Code Coverage for a dotnet core application through manual testing (I don't have any unit tests project)

As mentioned in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951089/how-to-use-ms-code-coverage-tool-in-command-line), I'm trying to use vsinstr for instrumentation and vsperfmon.

But when running the below command

```
vsinstr /coverage C:\Test\netcoreapp2.0\ConsoleAppCodeCoverageTest.dll
```

I get the below error.

```
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 15.0.27128 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

File to Process:
   C:\Test\netcoreapp2.0\ConsoleAppCodeCoverageTest.dll --> 
C:\Test\netcoreapp2.0\ConsoleAppCodeCoverageTest.dll
Original file backed up to 
C:\Test\netcoreapp2.0\ConsoleAppCodeCoverageTest.dll.orig

Error VSP1019: Internal error.  HRESULT=80004005
```

But if I use vsinstr on a .Net Framework application exe it works fine.

Any idea how to fix this of if there is any other approach to get code coverage for a dotnet core application through manual testing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77957521/892770

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have to be running Visual Studio Enterprise and it only works on Windows.

Related github [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/981).

If that isn't a problem for you, note [these](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/981#issuecomment-330062269) instructions:

> If you are working from within VS on tests targeting .NET Core, then you will need to add a reference to the Microsoft.CodeCoverage NuGet package to your test project, and update both the test and app-under-test projects to generate ‘Full’ debug info.

More details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md).

Comment: Thanks! We don't have any unit test projects. We are trying to get code coverage when testing the application manually.